# Link to top of section div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full bootstrap layout with a fixed-navbar 140px in height each of my div sections are to linked via the nav. When i click the link to go to the about section it seems to go directly to the h2 tag and not the start of the about section div. Is there a way i can use js to fix the cutoff issue?

```
<ul>
<li><a href>#about</a></li>
</ul>
```

section{padding: 5em 0 5em 0}

```
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h3>About Subheading</h3>
        <div class="about">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**Edited code view**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 140
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried myself and I'm unable to reproduce your issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27912/

You have a number of errors in the html you've posted such as a missing `href` attribute and extra `</div>` closing tags

Comment: I have navbar-static-top with a height of 140px  20px padding top and bottom. Does there need to be some offset when the link is clicked so it goes to the start of <section id="about">

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, still seems to jump to the section